# Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns - svelte

Tags: d3.js, transition, svelte

I have this `svelte` component in a file called `BarEl.svelte`

BarEl.svelte

```
<script>
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
  export let xValue;
  export let yValue;
  export let widthValue;
  export let heightValue;
  export let fillValue;
</script>

<rect
  x={xValue}
  y={yValue}
  width={widthValue}
  height={heightValue}
  fill={fillValue}
  stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2"
  in:fly={{y=-200, duration: 500 }}
/>
```

where I use it in another `svelte` component called `BarChart.svelte`

BarChart.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
 import BarEl from './BarEl.svelte';//Here TypeScript says BarEl.svelte has no default exports
</script>
...
{#each $PopulationStore as item (item.id)}
      <BarEl
        xValue={xScale(item.country)}
        yValue={yScale(item.population)}
        widthValue={xScale.bandwidth()}
        heightValue={innerHeight - yScale(item.population)}
        fillValue={colorScale(item.population)}
      />
    {/each}
```

I am facing two problems:

- TypeScript says BarEl.svelte has no default exports. What does this mean?
- When I try to animate the bars using the built-in `fly` transition, I get the error that `Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns`, and there is a squiggly red line under `y` in `in:fly={{y=-200,..}}`.

I don't know why these problem occur, and thus how to fix them. I appreciate any help

Comment: For your 2nd issue, it's a typo, you're passing an object and `y` is a property, so it should be `in:fly={{y: -200, .. }}`. No clue about your default export issue however, I've never had to explicitly export components. Maybe a configuration issue?

Comment: Oops, what a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing the mistake out. The transition still doesn't work, though. But this is another issue.

Comment: My guess for the "has no default export" issue is that it's a follow-up issue because of the typo. If the file is syntactically correct (typo is fixed) it should be able to recognize the default export.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding problem 1 - I'm guessing (but haven't checked) that you may need the lang="ts" on the script tag of BarE1.svelte?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).